# Sharing fish configuration across computers

Tags: fish, dot-files

I'm trying to share configurations across my computers (macOS and WSL2). Most of my configurations (abbreviations, plugins configuration) are by default in `fish_variables`  which is meant to be [platform independent](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5870#issuecomment-491488456). Unfortunately fish expands `~` by default, which means I can't share it properly across machines.

Right now, I have a different file for abbreviations that I have in a github repo, but it's tedious to either extract my abbreviations from `fish_variables` if I rely on `abbr -a` or edit my file manually.
And it's even worse for plugins, as they write directly to `fish_variables`, I need to extract manually their configurations to a different file every time I update their configurations.

Is there any proper way to share configurations accross different computers without extracting `fish_variables` every time?

Comment: Some comments on https://stackoverflow.com/q/71684483/7552